# Has using the HttpRuntime.Cache changed in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, httpruntime.cache

So, I was looking over my standard cache utility when preparing to unit test a controller and thought, hey, is accessing the HttpRuntime.Cache directly considered harmful in MVC?

I wrap the cache in a proxy class that implements a cache-like interface (tho much simpler) so that I can mock it during tests.  But I'm wondering if that's already done for me in the new framework.  I can't find anything, however.

Here's an idea of how I do it:

```
public ActionResult DoStuffLol(guid id)
{
  var model = CacheUtil.GetOrCreateAndStore(
                  "DoStuffLolModel",
                  () =>
                  {
                    /* construct model here; time consuming stuff */
                    return model;
                  });
  return View("DoStuffLol", model);
}
```

So, has the old patterns of accessing the cache changed?  Are there any better patterns for caching action results in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but the cache has changed in 3.5.  3.5 includes wrapper classes that make stubbing/mocking many of the static classes used in asp.net easy.

http://www.codethinked.com/post/2008/12/04/Using-SystemWebAbstractions-in-Your-WebForms-Apps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add the OutputCache attribute to your controller action in order to tell the framework to cache the output for you.  You can read more about this attribute in [ScottGu's blog post on ASP.NET Preview 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx).

[Don't combine this with the Authorize attribute](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/08/29/asp-net-mvc-tip-40-don-t-cache-pages-that-require-authorization.aspx), however.

Comment: This is only for caching the entire controller action.  To cache just pieces of data the mechanics haven't changed in ASP.Net MVC.